# AX 2009 - Append a character

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I'm pulling/querying the data from the table and I'm getting a dups. I want to append a character('A' and 'B" at the end of a value of the dups.

Here's the fragment of the code:

```
while select count(recid) from amtExport
       group by billOfLadingId
        where amtExport.createddatetime1 >= utcDT
    {
       if (amtExport.RecId == 2)
        {
           while select amtExport1
                where amtExport1.billOfLadingId == amtExport.billOfLadingId
              {
                 info(amtExport1.billOfLadingId);
              }

            }
        }
```

output:
00232763 
00232763 
00232793 
00232793 
00232800 
00232800
......
......

So, I'd like to append a single character at the end of the value, like

00232763A 
00232763B 
00232793A 
00232793B 
00232800A 
00232800B 
.......
......

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough...one thing I noticed is you're doing `RecId == 2`, but if there are more than 2 duplicates, they will be skipped. Consider changing to `RecId > 1`.

Also, there's no error checking, so if there are more than 26 duplicates, obviously the Ascii characters after `Z` will be used.

```
AMTExport       amtExport, amtExport1;
ASCII           asciiLetter;

while select count(RecId) from amtExport
    group by billOfLadingId
{
    if (amtExport.RecId == 2) // Should this be .RecId > 1?
    {
        asciiLetter = 65; // Reset letter to 'A'
        while select amtExport1
            where amtExport1.billOfLadingId == amtExport.billOfLadingId
        {
            info(amtExport.billOfLadingId + num2char(asciiLetter));
            asciiLetter++; // Increase the ascii letter
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm being silly but if you need only `billOfLadingId` and no other fields from amtExport then you don't have to do the second `while select`:

```
while select billOfLadingId, count(recid) from amtExport
       group by billOfLadingId
        where amtExport.createddatetime1 >= utcDT
    {
       if (amtExport.RecId > 1)
        {
           /*
           while select amtExport1
                where amtExport1.billOfLadingId == amtExport.billOfLadingId
              {
                 info(amtExport1.billOfLadingId);
              }
           */

           for (i = 1; i <= amtExport.RecId; i++)
           {
              info(amtExport1.billOfLadingId + num2char(64 + i));
           }
        }
    }
```